# Alternative for all_load in XCode's Other Linker Flags

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm adding [Rdio](http://developer.rdio.com/docs/read/iOS) to my iOS app and I'm stuck on this part of the installation:

> Add -all_load under Other Linker Flags in the project build info

If I add that flag, then another third party library breaks giving me the error message:

> ld: duplicate symbol _vw_chartype_table_p in /Users/josh/ 
>   Projects/app/libs/libvt_universal.a(vw_ctype-3279EF26D0C25F3A.o) and / 
>   Users/josh/Projects/app/libs/ 
>   libvt_universal.a(vw_ctype-34AB9EC0B46D954C.o) for architecture i386

**Is there any way to use the Rdio library without using -all_load?** For example, I've tried `-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/Rdio.framework` but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

force_load is exactly what you want - it allows you to load only that framework without messing with anything else.  The problem is the exact syntax along with a few other unexpected tweaks to your settings.

### -force_load syntax

Force load should be given the path to your *object file*, not the framework.

```
-force_load $(SOURCE_ROOT)/AppName/libs/Rdio.framework/Versions/Current/Rdio
```

### Other Settings

1. Remove `Rdio.framework` from the 'Link Binary with Libraries' build phase.
2. Remove '/libs/Rdio.framework' from my LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS