# phonegap and AdMob flag issue

Tags: cordova, admob, phonegap-plugins

I have this problem and I'm hoping to see if someone could help me, I have a project using phonegap 2.4 which is using the lastest AdMob sdk from google, its seems like this new google sdk needs to have a flag removed

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/KIJrPLou2ns/KyqrEWIvTLgJ

-all_load, from the Other Linker flags section

according to the docs this flag allow to load categories even though there is no code in them (not sure what it means but anyway), so if I removed the flag I can build for a device, but phonegap is using on CDVViewController on line 165

self.pluginsMap = [delegate.pluginsDict dictionaryWithLowercaseKeys];

where dictionaryWithLowercaseKeys needs that flag, these seems to be due to an ios 6 support, so I don't know which has the blame, phonegap not ready to ios 6 or google sdk, so my question is

if there someone that was able to successfully use AdMob sdk with phone 2.4 and ios 6??, or I missing something, please any idea, thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `-all_load` flag was required by many libraries due to an iOS bug that was fixed in iOS 6. The AdMob SDK requires that you don't have the `-all_load` flag anymore.

If you for some reason need to load a specific library, you can use the [-force_load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809304/alternative-for-all-load-in-xcodes-other-linker-flags) flag.