# Cordova: Build Without "-all_load"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am having an issue while building an iOS app with Cordova and a third-party plugin that ships with a native SDK. Cordova requires Linker Flag "-all_load" which other SDK is not happy about.

I read this post about "-all_load" flag: [Alternative for all_load in XCode's Other Linker Flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809304/alternative-for-all-load-in-xcodes-other-linker-flags;It) sounds like I might be able to use "-force_load" instead and specify the "object file" that Cordova wants.

I do not know much about the Cordova's internals. Has anyone had the same problem and was successfully able to compile Cordova with "force_load"? Could you provide your *Cordova specific* "force_load" syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that libraries containing categories did not properly load in earlier versions of Xcode. As of 4.6 they should be loading, and you **should** be able to just use the linker flag "-ObjC", which tells the linker to examine the libraries for such things.

If for some reason the -ObjC flag does not work, the syntax for the force load is"

```
-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libxyz.a
```

Comment: Sorry - the explanation helps but I should have been more specific. I am looking for the library(ies) that Cordova tries to cover with "all_load" so I can write the appropriate "force_load" switches. The question is specific to Cordova.

Comment: So look at their library and get all the ones they reference, and do it all as above - that is, anything that is not iOS provided.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to pointers from @David H, I was able to replace the Other Linker Flags "-all_load" switch by:

```
-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a
```

Cordova now compiles and starts fine without breaking my other libraries that do not like "-all_load"