# "ld: file not found: -Obj-C" while trying to add Cordova as component (Cleaver)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, linker, clang

I'm adding Cordova as a component into my iOS project generated by [an Empty application template](https://github.com/featherJ/Empty-Application-For-Xcode-7).

I've followed the steps [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/webview.html) (in one part it mentions about adding `-force_load` and `-Obj-C` for the Other Linker Flags value.) and when I tried to build the application I ran into this error:

> ld: file not found: -Obj-C
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

where we have

> ...LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.2 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode-marker -force_load -Obj-C -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos ...

Am I getting this error because I should be passing a filepath as parameter to `-force_load`? 
I'd appreciate if someone can tell me what is going on and how I can fix this. Thanks.

p.s. I'm using XCode 7.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those instructions are broken as `-force_load` expects an argument, which is why `-Obj-C` is showing *file not found*.

From the `ld` manual:

> `-force_load path_to_archive`
>       Loads all members of the specified static archive library.  Note: `-all_load` forces all members of all archives to be loaded.  This option allows you to target a specific archive.

Unless you know the name of the library to *force load* you may as well drop that argument and leave `-Obj_C` in the *Other Linker Flags*.  I believe that will work on its own anyway.

EDIT: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683090/cordova-build-without-all-load) shows you can just use:

```
-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a
```