# Dupplicate symbols errors when adding OpenKit

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

I'm trying to add a leaderboard to my game by using [OpenKit](http://openkit.io/documentation/) Framework. Following their documentation, I've added all the neccessay libs + framwork but the following errors occured :

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFOAuth1Client._applicationLaunchNotificationObserver in:
  /Users/Sa7bi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/helloworld-erlcedkitaorqobgauzlzyvacnfi/Build/Intermediates/helloworld.build/Debug-iphoneos/helloworld.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/AFOAuth1Client.o
  /Users/Sa7bi/Dropbox/Aliens Wings/HelloWorld/OpenKitSDK/libOpenKit.a(AFOAuth1Client.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFOAuth1Client._key in:
  /Users/Sa7bi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/helloworld-erlcedkitaorqobgauzlzyvacnfi/Build/Intermediates/helloworld.build/Debug-iphoneos/helloworld.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/AFOAuth1Client.o
  /Users/Sa7bi/Dropbox/Aliens Wings/HelloWorld/OpenKitSDK/libOpenKit.a(AFOAuth1Client.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFOAuth1Client._secret in:
  /Users/Sa7bi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/helloworld-erlcedkitaorqobgauzlzyvacnfi/Build/Intermediates/helloworld.build/Debug-iphoneos/helloworld.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/AFOAuth1Client.o
  /Users/Sa7bi/Dropbox/Aliens Wings/HelloWorld/OpenKitSDK/libOpenKit.a(AFOAuth1Client.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFOAuth1Client._signatureMethod in:
  /Users/Sa7bi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/helloworld-erlcedkitaorqobgauzlzyvacnfi/Build/Intermediates/helloworld.build/Debug-iphoneos/helloworld.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/AFOAuth1Client.o
  /Users/Sa7bi/Dropbox/Aliens Wings/HelloWorld/OpenKitSDK/libOpenKit.a(AFOAuth1Client.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFOAuth1Client._realm in:
  /Users/Sa7bi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/helloworld-erlcedkitaorqobgauzlzyvacnfi/Build/Intermediates/helloworld.build/Debug-iphoneos/helloworld.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/AFOAuth1Client.o
  /Users/Sa7bi/Dropbox/Aliens Wings/HelloWorld/OpenKitSDK/libOpenKit.a(AFOAuth1Client.o)
....
ld: 19 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7s
```

While searching on this website, some users suggested the following:

- Compilation of the same file more than once ==> checked my [Build Phases | Compile Sources] nothing
- Importing ".m" files instead of ".h" ==> checked all my imports, nothing

I really have no idea what is causing this.
**Update**: I have forget to mention that Google Ads SDK is included in my projet. When I delete the "-ObjC" linker flag, OpenKit works fine but Google doesn't.

Comment: Are you using the iOS SDK or using the Unity SDK?

Comment: No I'm actually using iOS SDK (Xcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many weeks of search, I've found a solution. Instead of using the "-ObjC" linker flag for Google Ads, "force_load" was the perfect solution.
The "-ObjC" flag was messing with the OpenKit lib, according to the folks @OpenKit:

> The problem is that the -ObjC flag loads all categories, and we removed some categories from the OpenKit SDK to make it work without using that flag.

[image]

> **force_load** :load only that framework without messing with anything else.[[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10851294/711388)